# Json Array loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on asp.net visual studio. I am calling a web method using jquery.
In asp.net I am creating a dynamic datatable.I am returning  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)`;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default.aspx/GetCustomers',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {

        console.log((result.d));
        cars = result.d;
        $.each(cars, function (index, key) {

            console.log(index);
            console.log(key);

        })

    }
});
```

This is the json returning from asp.net

```
[{"Name":"Jones","January 2019":53.0000,"February 2019":33.0000,"March 2019":55.0000 }]
```

When I loop through it $.each I am getting an error

> SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

How can I access key and values?

Comment: Try `$.each(cars[0], function (index, key) {` It looks like it's seeing an array where it expects an object, which is inside the array.

Comment: Are you seeing expected json array output in console via console.log((result.d));? Also, what is the data type of result.d is it string or object?

Comment: @sam : output is this [{"Name":"Jones","January 2019":53.0000,"February 2019":33.0000,"March 2019":55.0000 }]

Comment: Is that what is in `result.d` or just `result`?

Comment: console.log(result.d) is  [{"Name":"Jones","January 2019":53.0000,"February 2019":33.0000,"March 2019":55.0000 }]

Comment: Did you try my first comment? That should yield the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through this JSON:

```js
const cars = [{
  "Name": "Jones",
  "January 2019": 53.0000,
  "February 2019": 33.0000,
  "March 2019": 55.0000
}]

// jQuery
$.each(cars, function(index, key) {
  const car = Object.entries(key)
  console.log('$.each()')
  $.each(car, function(i, el) {
    console.log('key:', el[0])
    console.log('val:', el[1])
  })
})

// JavaScript
cars.forEach(e => {
  console.log('forEach()')
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(e)) {
    console.log(`key: ${key}`)
    console.log(`val: ${val}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think the key is **Object.entries()**.

More on **Object.entries()**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using Object.Keys as below:

```js
var cars = [
 {
  "Name": "Jones",
  "January 2019": 53.0000,
  "February 2019": 33.0000,
  "March 2019": 55.0000
 }
];

$.each(cars,
 function(index, dict) {

  console.log(index);
  console.log(dict);

  Object.keys(dict)
   .forEach(function eachKey(key) { // or .forEach(function (key) { 
    console.log(key + ': ' + dict[key]); 
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```